# Tab order with MFC ActiveX control

Tags: c++, winforms, mfc, activex

We have an MFC ActiveX control, created in Visual Studio 2012, with CLR support, that hosts a .NET UserControl via a member variable of type `CWinFormsControl<T>`.  On creation of the MFC ActiveX control, the `CWinFormsControl` is created and expanded to cover the entire ActiveX control.

All works well in several containers (including my VB6 test form), with exception of the TAB key.  The tab key navigates to each item until it encounters my ActiveX control, at which point the focus is lost completely and the TAB key becomes useless.  The mouse must be used to recover.

Eventually, found that

```
BOOL CMyCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (IsDialogMessage(pMsg))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return COleControl::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

in the MFC ActiveX control seems to focus into the .NET UserControl.  However, once inside the .NET UserControl, focus continually cycles among the items of the .NET UserControl and never leaves.  The user must use the mouse to get out of the ActiveX/.NET control, back to the rest of the application.

Is the `PreTranslateMessage` the right approach?  Any thoughts on how to handle TABs to/from a `CWinFormsControl<T>` object?

Regards,

Andrew